# Best practices for php project organization using GIT?

Tags: php, git

I'm working on releasing a PHP framework I have been using for a few years
on github. Been trying to read up on the most correct way a project
should be structured, what extra files such as readme's etc should be
added. Been coming up with blanks on google. Can anyone point me to a
project that's a good example or any good write ups.

Comment: Can you outline the objective of your framework?  I would help with repo layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some PHP projects hosted on Git(hub) include:

- [CakePHP](http://github.com/cakephp/cakephp1x)
- [Gallery3](http://github.com/gallery/gallery3)
- [Garden](http://github.com/lussumo/Garden)
- [PHPUnit](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit)
- [Kohana](http://github.com/kohana)

I'd just make sure that no temporary files, etc. get in the repository by creating a `.gitignore` file, and add some readme's etc. to the root of the repository.

Any configuration files should also be ignored, and sample configuration files should be created in the repository.

I'd recommend writing the readme file in a format that [Github supports](http://github.com/guides/readme-formatting), like Markdown. It'll make your repository front page look better.

You might want to follow some kind of class naming guideline to make things like autoloading easier to implement. For example, the class `MyFramework_Controller` should be located at directory `/lib/MyFramework/Controller.php`.

You should just create some kind of basic layout for now - it'll be easier to give suggestions when we can see what you have right now.